# Record audioqueue result to audio file

Tags: ios, audio-recording, audioqueueservices

I use https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer for playing stream, it use AudioQueue to play stream.

I want to record result of playing, i read [AudioQueueProgrammingGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/musicaudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW15) but as i see we can use only microphone on device to record audio via AudioQueue.

How i can record this audioQueue that we have when playing stream via AudioStreamer to audio file?

Comment: You should have no problem writing the buffers using Audio File Services https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/musicaudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AudioFileWritePackets

Comment: @MDB983 ok now i will try it

Comment: if you get stuck, post some code and i'll be glad to help